# How can UITests detect elements on UITableView backgroundView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to detect, through UITesting, if a button exists in a *UITableView.backgroundView*, and tap it.

I use this *backgroundView* to show an empty state view when the tableView has no items to be shown. 
In this empty state view, I have a button to perform some other action.

When doing a UITest case for this specific scenario, I can't figure out a way to find the button.

Has anyone come across this problem?

I've already tried to mess with some accessibility options and posting accessibility notifications but with no success.

```swift
let emptyStateViewController = EmptyViewController() // button is in this view controller's view
self.addChildViewController(emptyStateViewController)
self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyStateViewController.view
```

sample print of the XCUIApplication object:

```
 NavigationBar, 0x600001226300, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, identifier: 'Title'
    Other, 0x600001228540, {{168.5, 32.5}, {38.5, 20.5}}, label: 'Title'
Other, 0x600001228620, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 647.0}}
    Other, 0x60000122d500, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 647.0}}
        Table, 0x60000122d880, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 647.0}}, label: 'first text label from the empty state view'
```

I can make *backgroundView* detectable by setting *isAccessibilityElement* to *true* and add an *accessibilityIdentifier*. This would allow me to know if the empty state view is on being presented, but still would not be possible to tap the button inside of it.

```swift
let emptyStateViewController = EmptyViewController() // button is in this view controller's view
emptyStateViewController.view.isAccessibilityElement = true
emptyStateViewController.view.accessibilityIdentifier = "empty_state_view"
self.addChildViewController(emptyStateViewController)
self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyStateViewController.view
```

The print will be:

```
NavigationBar, 0x600000057640, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, identifier: 'Title'
    Other, 0x600000057720, {{168.5, 32.5}, {38.5, 20.5}}, label: 'Title'
Other, 0x600000057800, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 647.0}}
    Other, 0x6000000578e0, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 647.0}}
        Table, 0x6000000579c0, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 647.0}}
            Other, 0x600000057aa0, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 647.0}}, identifier: 'empty_state_view'
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't do `emptyStateViewController.view.someButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "empty_state_view_button"`?

Comment: @Chris still won't work. The print will still finish on ```Table, 0x60000122d880, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 647.0}}, label: 'first text label from the empty state view'```
Also, for buttons, that wouldn't be necessary as the UITests can take either the accessibility identifier or the button title.